# O que posso fazer no .NET Framework e no .NET Core não? E vice-versa

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Cresci o olho em cima do .NET Core (ASP.NET Core), comecei com C#, mas abandonei por partir para o lado "*open-source*", agora com essa oportunidade resolvi "voltar".

Pretendo utilizar o .NET Core (ASP.NET Core) em um projeto pessoal e futuramente estabelecer ele como opção de desenvolvimento.

Em pesquisas vi que é muito falado que existe "restrições" entre os dois lados, e isso é crucial para decidir se é o ideal para um projeto:

- O que posso fazer com o .NET Framework (ASP.NET 1.0) que no .NET Core (ASP.NET Core) não?  Vice-Versa.
- Tem um vão muito grande de diferenças entre os dois?
- Vale a pena investir nele no momento?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Esta pergunta passa fazer pouco sentido agora porque [o .NET Framework morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101), só sobrou o .NET Core, que passa ser chamado apenas de .NET. Principalmente a conclusão desta resposta já não importa mais.

---

Há uma [página indicando o que é a nova proposta de .NET Platform Standard](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/Documentation/architecture/net-platform-standard.md). Isso talvez seja o mais importante. Se quer algo portável entre as variadas implementações que conformem com isso tem que se ater a isto. Qualquer coisa que use e não está nesta lista, não há garantias que funcionará em outras implementações.

Comparar com ASP.NET 1.0 não é prudente.

As duas principais vantagens do .NET Core é rodar em diversas plataformas (não só sistemas operacionais, realmente é uma tecnologia mais aberta) e não precisar de nada previamente instalado, inclusive permitindo uma instalação modular das dependências (pra mim a principal). Disto surgem diversas outras pequenas vantagens. Além de ter novas funcionalidades, mais modernas, e mais bem pensadas.

Seria complicado fazer uma lista completa do que não existe no .NET Core porque essa lista é bem extensa se for em todos detalhes e ela vai encurtando a cada dia.

Nem falarei das diferenças para o desenvolver. Isso dá-se um jeito.

Quase tudo o que tiraram foi por uma boa razão.

Longe de dizer que o .NET Core terá tudo o que o .NET Framework (esse antigo que sempre usamos). Explicitamente isso não ocorrerá. Mas muito do que não existe hoje deverá ter em algum momento.

O que dá para dizer é que a muita coisa ligada ao Windows não terá. Como o Core foi feito para ser portável, essas coisas foram deixadas de fora. Mas algumas nem no Windows fazia sentido mais.

- <strike>Então não tem Windows Forms e WPF. Mas tem UWP, que obviamente não poderá ser usado fora do Windows</strike>. Isto não é mais verdade, embora esses 3 ainda só funcionem no Windows. E existem opções de terceiros para GUI.
- <strike>`System.Drawing` ainda não está disponível</strike>. Isto não é mais verdade.
- Muitas coisas que só fazem sentido no Windows, como Enterprise.Services. Qualquer coisa que dependa de P/Invoke está fora, mas algumas poderão ter substitutos, provavelmente mais modernos. COM também tem limitações.
- ASP.NET tradicional (WebForms) não é suportado. Mas mesmo o MVC antigo não pode funcionar porque depende do tradicional (isto mudou um pouco). Não sei se há algum esforço para mudar isso, mas duvido. O ASP.NET Core é parecido com o ASP.NET MVC, mas não idêntico e compatível. O [Blazor](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/288706/101) tem modelo parecido mas é melhor
- A integração com servidores HTTP é bem diferença e ainda tem limitações. Apesar de agora ter uma base para ser melhor.
- <strike>Assim como o Entity Framework antigo também não funciona. O novo é melhor, mas demora um pouco para estar completo (sem o legado do antigo)</strike>. Isto não é mais verdade no Windows.
- O WCF tem bastante limitação. Tem soluções melhores que ele agora.
- Reflexão tem alguma limitação também, mas nada importante.
- Serialização binária não está disponível por padrão, mas tem opções melhores.
- Não há [domínio de aplicação](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/application-domains?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) (AppDomain). Ainda bem.
- A segurança da aplicação é bem simplificada (isso não quer dizer que é inseguro). Não há ([CAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/930b76w0(v=vs.90)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397)). Já não é mais importante como era.
- Não dá e nem faz sentido ter *click once*. Não faz sentido mais usar isto, e tem o MSIX ou soluções de terceiros muito melhores e tem o executável *standalone* que acaba sendo mais interessante.
- Tiraram boa parte do que era considerado obsoleto. Há uma [lista oficial de obsolescência](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/whats-new/obsolete-types?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).
- Tem várias outras coisas, esta lista não está completa, mas agora já é uma lista bem menor e nada importante.

Enfim, pense no .NET Core como uma nova tecnologia. Existem casos para continuar usando o *framework* tradicional. Em geral não vale a pena converter aplicações antigas para o .NET Core, a não ser que tenha um bom motivo. Mas na maioria dos casos é interessante usar o .NET Core. Ele é *game changing* para o .NET.

Responder qual é o melhor para cada projeto seu não é nossa função. Cabe perguntas mais específicas sobre recursos que vai precisar.

Muita gente acha que vale a pena investir nele, de fato nunca vi uma tecnologia nova ter adoção tão rápida como esta, mas você deve formar sua própria opinião. Certamente tem gente que pensa o contrário.

Só começando fazer para saber. Lembre-se que tudo é diferente. Você ainda não sabe como usá-lo. Terá dificuldades iniciais. Ele tem filosofia diferente e é um pouco mais bruto. Acho que está pensando certo. Dê uma passo de cada vez.

O .NET Framework continuará suportado <strike>e terá alguma evolução</strike>, mas o foco está no .NET Core.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Fantastico @bigown, pensava próximo ao que você disse, agora ficou concreto e sera o que vou seguir. Encarando como uma nova tecnologia(conceito/filosofia) que ele é, arriscando e aprendendo a desenvolver sobre as diferenças e novidades. Obrigado.

Comment: @Marcial, estou atualmente pesquisando e implementando alguns novos projetos para essa tecnologia e a principal dificuldade que encontro nem é a própria plataforma, mas sim _libraries_ de terceiros como drivers de banco de dados (no meu caso [`Firebird .Net Provider`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/en/net-provider/)), e no meu caso o ORM em si (`NHibernate`). Utilizo Asp.Net Core pelas vantagens e facilidades em utilizar npm e bower, pelo novo modelo de projeto (mais organizado em minha opinião) e simplicidade nos mecanismo de Injeção de Dependências, entre outros motivos menores. [continua...]

Comment: [continuando...] Para isso acabei alterando o _target/framework_ de meu projeto para `.NET Framework` ao invés de `.NET Core`, sendo que apesar de utilizar toda a nova abordagem de projetos `Core`, consigo utilizar as _libraries_ antigas, com o custo de não ter a vantagem de multiplataforma do `.Net Core`. Minha expectativa é no futuro ao ter os recursos necessários para `.Net Core` , retornar o _target/framework_ de minha aplicação para `.Net Core` novamente!

Comment: @Fernando é claro que você não terá o *port* de todas bibliotecas de um dia para o outro, se você usa alguma tecnologia que ainda não está disponível para ele tem que aguardar para fazer algo sério. Mas pode ir aprendendo o que tem diferente. Tem várias coisas melhores. Algumas das desvantagens são transitórias. Outras são propositais.

Comment: Entendo sua posição/atitude @Fernando e concordo, porem na minha situação eu posso optar por qualquer stack de tecnologia, principalmente por ser um projeto pessoal e estar encarando o .Net Core como uma tecnologia nova como o bigown falou. E conceitualmente falando, esta sendo aquilo que procurava, uma tecnologia nova, um .Net aberto e de uma forma que me agrada mais. Vou ir aprendendo e adaptando conforme corre.

Comment: Correto @Marcial, meu comentário realmente foi com a intenção de alertar sobre esse tipo de problema com _library_ de terceiros, mas se você pode utilizar essas dependências conforme disponibilidade, o `.Net Core` só irá lhe ser agregador, pois toda a tecnologia foi refeita e melhorada, muito do que era legado de versões passadas e que acabava limitando o avanço da tecnologia foi repensado. No meu ponto de vista isso está sendo um grande avanço na tecnologia .Net, "é um passo para traz para dar 2 passos para a frente".

Answer (score 7):

Para ter a resposta e entendimento desta pergunta, antes é preciso olhar a imagem abaixo que exemplifica bem o status atual da plataforma .NET:

[image: .NET Framework 4.6 e .NET Core 1.0]

Existem dois Frameworks. Sendo o `.NET Framework 4.6` o mais maduro, por ter anos de desenvolvimento e produção. Este, apelidado por *"Full Framework"*, está disponível apenas para aplicações Windows. Ou seja, aplicações que rodam em Windows Server, dependem do IIS e dos componentes que ali se instalam também e fazem dependência deste universo. Para o Full Framework podemos trabalhar apenas com o ASP.NET 4.6. E assim, utilizar todo os recursos do ASP.NET 4.6.

O segundo framework, chamado de `.NET Core`, que atualmente está na versão 1.1, está disponível para ambientes Windows, Linux e OSX. Ou seja, é o que chamamos de cross-platform ou multi-plataforma. Por enquanto as aplicações desenvolvidas com o `.NET Core` comparados ao Full Framework são mais limitados em recurso. Porém, já na versão **1.1** do `.NET Core` temos uma certa estabilidade e várias funcionalidades interessantes e que nos traz independência de server, ambiente e plataforma de desenvolvimento.

**Importante**: Aplicações .NET Core podem rodar em ambientes com `.NET Core` ou com o `.NET Framework 4.6` instalados. Porém o contrário não é possível.

> Outro detalhe: Você pode desenvolver uma aplicação em ASP.NET Core 1.1
>   e utilizar bibliotecas do .NET Standard. Porém, ao fazer isto, a sua
>   aplicação deixa de ser cross-platform.

***O que posso fazer com o .Net Framework (ASP.NET 1.0) que no .Net Core (ASP.NET Core) não? Vice-Versa.***

- Documentação .NET Core: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/articles/core/
- Documentação .NET Framework: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w0x726c2(v=vs.110).aspx

***Tem um vão muito grande de diferenças entre os dois?***

O .NET Core foi reescrito. Para quem estava acostumado do Visual Studio fazer tudo, pode não aproveitar todo o suprassumo do .NET Core. Acho que a independência na manipulação do ambiente de desenvolvimento é uma das maiores diferenças. Programaticamente, não há grandes dificuldades.

***Vale a pena investir nele no momento?***

Sim. Bastante!

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta. Dês a criação dessa pergunta, venho pesquisando e investindo no .Net Core e Asp.net Core, ate já assisti uns vídeos de vocês. Estava a procura de algo multiplataforma, já havia estudado C# com o full framework, então acabou caindo bem. Venho utilizando ubuntu com visual code, posso estar perdendo bastante coisa em não usar o visual studio, mas é principalmente para ter algo mais "simples" e direto como o Core é.

Comment: Não tinha visto sua resposta aqui, legal Kono.