# Qual é a sintaxe correta para usar orientação a objetos em C# usando o .NET Core?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos, sintaxe, .net-core

Tenho que me familiarizar com implementação do código orientação a objeto no desenvolvimento C#. No entanto, os materiais que estou aprendendo supõem que eu tenho ambiente Windows e Visual Studio instalado ([exemplo](https://www.caelum.com.br/apostila-csharp-orientacao-objetos/classes-e-objetos/#6-1-organizando-o-codigo-com-objetos)). Quando pesquiso material a respeito acabo me deparando com tutoriais de orientação a objeto que pouco tem haver com meu problema específico (que é fazer isso usando .NET Core).

Então imagino que deva ter alguma importação (no C# usam a expressão `using` + a importação), qualquer coisa que permita que eu apenas me ambiente a usar OOP.

Estou tentando implementar com o seguinte código:

```
using System;

namespace hwapp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           objeto c = new Program();
    c.numero = 12;
    c.titular = "João";
    c.saldo = 102;

    Console.WriteLine("Número: "+c.numero+"\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Titular da conta: "+c.titular+"\n");
    Console.WriteLine("Salto: "+c.saldo+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Ao dar o comando `dotnet run`, retorna a seguinte mensagem

> Program.cs(9,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'objeto' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/home/upgrade/dotnet/hwapp/hwapp.csproj]

> The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.

Leituras recomendadas:

[O que posso fazer no .NET Framework e no .NET Core não? E vice-versa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156517/101)

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/articles/core/

Answer (score 9):

Qualquer material que ensine uma [linguagem em cima de um IDE](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/101691/101) não é um bom material pra se aprender linguagem. Inclusive não gosto do material que está usando, mas é só minha opinião.

O C# é a mesma linguagem não importa em qual [*runtime*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/51281/101) ou sistema operacional que está rodando. Então se aprender a linguagem com um bom material pode usar esse conhecimento de forma idêntica em todo lugar. O [.NET Core](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40671/101) é só uma base escrita de forma diferente para usar a mesma coisa. Claro que as [bibliotecas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/17501/101) não básicas podem ter algumas diferenças para atender o objetivo dele que é diferente do .NET Framework ([que morreu](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/385594/101)). E não dá para fazer algo universal como algumas pessoas acreditavam ou acreditam até hoje que dá.

Orientação a objeto é só uma organização de código. Ou você sabe OOP ou não sabe, isto independe de linguagem. E devo dizer que poucas pessoas sabem realmente o que é e como fazer OO corretamente, a maioria só acha que sabe, vide  [efeito Dunning-Kugger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect). Orientação a objeto é só um paradigma secundário.

O código apresentado não tem nada nem perto do OOP. Na verdade tem um erro de digitação, o tipo deveria ser `object` e não `objeto`. De qualquer forma aquilo não deveria ser do tipo `object`. Este código é absolutamente procedural e sem sentido. porque acessa membros que não existem no tipo `object`.

Recomendo escolher um material que ensine em passos, que só entre em orientação a objeto quando dominar o básico. Veja [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23).

Isto provavelmente causará mais confusão do que ajudar, mas algo que seria na linha do que está desejando:

```
using static System.Console;

public class Program {
    public static void Main(string[] args) {
        var conta = new Conta(1, "Joao", 100M);
        WriteLine(conta.Sacar(103.45M) ? $"Saque realizado, saldo restante {conta.Saldo}" : "Não foi possível sacar");
        conta.Depositar(50.0M);
        conta.Titular = "Joao da Silva";
        WriteLine(conta.Sacar(103.45M) ? $"Saque realizado, saldo restante {conta.Saldo}" : "Não foi possível sacar");
        WriteLine($"Número: {conta.Numero}");
        WriteLine($"Titular da conta: {conta.Titular}");
        WriteLine($"Saldo: {conta.Saldo}");
    }
}

public class Conta {
    public int Numero { get; set; }
    public string Titular { get; set; }
    public decimal Saldo { get; set; }
    public Conta(int numero, string titular, decimal saldo) {
        Numero = numero;
        Titular = titular;
        Saldo = saldo;
    }
    public void Depositar(decimal valor) => Saldo += valor;

    public bool Sacar(decimal valor) {
        if (Saldo - valor >= 0) {
            Saldo -= valor;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/LUF43k). E [no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kUA0A0). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/bigown/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Class/BasicExample.cs).

Obviamente que isto é uma enorme simplificação. Uma classe real teria muito mais complexa. Isto é orientado a objeto? Em parte. Há encapsulamento, e só. OOP é muito mais complexo que isso, mas de forma simplificada, partindo de que não precisa de outras complexidades pode ser considerado OO.

Então o erro aí é exclusivamente de digitação e uso indevido de campos, nada tem a ver com estar no Linux, ser .NET Core, ou estar usando OOP. Existe um problema do código ser muito ruim, principalmente se está querendo fazer OOP.

Sobre o [`using` precisa saber para que ele serve](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/16563/101). Não faz o menor sentido importar nomes de algo que faz parte da linguagem e não da biblioteca.

**Importante notar que a resposta do AP mantém as mesmas premissas erradas da pergunta e incorpora mais algumas**. É normal quando a pessoa desconhece os fatos, mas fica o alerta para quem está aprendendo.

- Um [exemplo de código mais razoavelmente orientado a objeto em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/170017/101) que acho que já conhece.
- [Significado da terminologia: "Orientado a objeto"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/88546/101)
- [O que é "Orientado a objeto" e quais outros métodos?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/108047/101)
- [O que é paradigma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/141624/101)
- [Programação Funcional e Programação Orientada a Objetos. O que são e quais suas principais diferenças?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13372/101)
- Também seria bom saber sobre [tipagem estática e dinâmica](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21508/101) e [estilo de tipagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/190463/101).

Comment: O ponto é quero praticar os exercícios. Quero ver rodando. 
E simplesmente não consigo fazer isso no .NET CORE .
E ainda tem o problema de nem tudo usado no .NET framework ser usado no .NET CORE.

Comment: Quando você voltar, eu gostaria que complementasse com a resposta do stackoverflow em inglês:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965452/how-to-program-in-oop-by-c-sharp-in-net-core/43965612#43965612

Também preciso almoçar :)

Comment: O primeiro comentário não faz sentido, não tem relevância para o problema. A resposta lá resolve o problema, mas desensina. Siga aquilo e fará errado pra sempre.

Comment: Verdade! Mas por sorte eu descobri duas coisas erradas em matéria tanto de C# quanto de OOP, que fiz com aquela implementação. Depois do almoço eu vou descrever isso, e isso talvez ajude aqueles que estiverem aprendendo e passando pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: Acabei de ver o final da edição do seu post. Quando eu voltar mostro porque tem mais do que erro de digitação.

Comment: É, tem o uso de variáveis locais como se fossem campos, que eu falo no começo.

Comment: Tem mais que isso. Em breve eu posto!

Comment: "Orientação a objeto é só uma organização de código" +1. E se pudesse daria outro pela menção a D/K.

Comment: @OnoSendai que acabou se mostrando a coisa mais importante de toda resposta :D

Answer (score -6):

O problema foi solucionado com as questões abaixo.

**Erros envolvendo C#**

> Então imagino que deva ter alguma importação (no C# usam a expressão
>   "using" + a importaçao), qualquer coisa que permita que eu apenas me
>   ambiente a usar OOP.

A resposta é **não!** Não é necessário o uso de nenhuma importação/biblioteca/framework adicional para testar recursos do paradigma orientado a objetos. O C# nativamente trabalha orientado a objetos, e o insucesso do teste realizado tem haver com a falta de conhecimento do AP em relação a implementação do C# com esse paradigma, e uso de material didático inchado (que limita a certo ambiente de desenvolvimento). Os erros serão comentados a seguir.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           objeto c = new Program();
    c.numero = 12;
    c.titular = "João";
    c.saldo = 102;
```

Na terceira linha, o código está seguindo o exemplo do material didático.

```
Conta c = new Conta();
```

Só que mesmo no material didático, a classe Conta já tinha tido declarada os tipo de seus atributos.

```
class Conta
{
    int numero;
    string titular;
    double saldo;
}
```

O erro principal foi não declarar os tipos dos atributos no código de exemplo. Esse defeito foi corrigido pelo StackOverFlow em inglês.

```
using System;

namespace hwapp {
    class Program {
        // Aqui embaixo está a correção dos atributos
        int numero;
        string titular;
        int saldo;

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var conta = new Program(); // linha corrigida
            conta.numero = 12;
            conta.titular = "João";
            conta.saldo = 102;

            Console.WriteLine("Número: "+conta.numero.ToString()+"\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Titular da conta: "+conta.titular+"\n");
            Console.WriteLine("Saldo: "+conta.saldo.ToString()+"\n");
        }
    }
}
```

**Erros de conceituação do paradigma orientado a objetos**

Sobre essa linha..

```
objeto c = new Program();
```

Mesmo se "objeto" fosse o objeto de fato, ele não foi "setado", então não existe. A explicação porque o material didático fez isso já foi dita acima. Vale citar que o AP não tinha intenção de usar a sintaxe "object", que eu não sabia que existia em C#. Outro problema é o título original da pergunta:

> Como programar orientação a objetos em C# usando o .NET CORE?

Embora ainda seja programação a pergunta, ela pode induzir o usuário do SOPT a dissertar sobre paradigma de Orientação a Objetos (o conceito), e não o problema da implementação (o código). Por exemplo, pode ser levantada questões se, um código que não use algum dos pilares do paradigma OOP (abstração, encapsulamento, herança e polimorfismo) é de fato OOP. Um defensor purista do paradigma pode alegar que deva existir uso completo dos pilares. Seu opositor vai alegar que excesso de herança causa acoplamento. No final nenhum dos dois abordará a implementação em C# (que sempre tem diferenças entre uma linguagem e outra). Por este motivo, após a edição deste post, o título da pergunta e partes do conteúdo será alterado. Ainda sobre um terceiro erro do AP envolvendo OOP, é supor que deva haver um adicional de qualquer forma. Esse erro também foi citado nos erros envolvendo C#. Se tal ferramenta alega que nativamente dá suporte a OOP, pelo menos qualquer adicional não deveria ser instalado/importado/etc. Talvez essa "bizarrice" exista em alguma ferramenta mas é passível de críticas. Abaixo código da classe funcionando sem importação.

```
namespace hwapp {
    class Program {
        // Aqui embaixo está a correção dos atributos
        int numero;
        string titular;
        int saldo;

        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var conta = new Program(); // linha corrigida
            conta.numero = 12;
            conta.titular = "João";
            conta.saldo = 102;

        }
    }
}
```

O máximo que acontece é um Warning de dados não sendo utilizados

```
Program.cs(6,13): warning CS0414: The field 'Program.numero' is assigned but its value is never used [/home/upgrade/dotnet/hwapp/hwapp.csproj]
Program.cs(8,13): warning CS0414: The field 'Program.saldo' is assigned but its value is never used [/home/upgrade/dotnet/hwapp/hwapp.csproj]
Program.cs(7,16): warning CS0414: The field 'Program.titular' is assigned but its value is never used [/home/upgrade/dotnet/hwapp/hwapp.csproj]
```

Sobre um quarto erro envolvendo esse tópico, está no conceito de CamelCase. Isso não necessariamente é um erro de OOP, mas de boas práticas. Mas que induziu um erro de OOP ao não notar a sintaxe da classe Conta.

O problema foi solucionado buscando informações destes conceitos.

Resposta do StackOverFlow em inglês:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43965452/how-to-program-in-oop-by-c-sharp-in-net-core

Orientação a objetos

https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/cc580626.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Sobre CamelCase

https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase

Comment: Praticamente nada disso faz sentido, e tem vários erros, induzindo quem não sabe a achar que tudo aí é verdade, o que é bem pouco. Portanto se os problemas desta resposta não forem resolvidos, serei obrigado negativar para evitar que as pessoas se enganem.

Comment: Você pode usar a sessão de respostas ou de comentários para apontar estes erros, e eventualmente eles serem corrigidos (se eles existirem). 
No entanto, foram estas questões que solucionaram meu problema, em parte no StackOverflow em inglês, em parte refletindo sobre as questões do C# e usando a documentação oficial. Tanto que consigo continuar os exercícios do material citado sem problemas. 
Não posso comentar com você sobre orientação a objeto, porque é um assunto extenso, e foge do escopo do site. Já o problema do código foi resolvido.

Comment: Não porque aqui não é um fórum. Se você deseja aprender tudo errado é problema seu, a chance de aprender certo foi dada. Pra falar a verdade eu nem achava que essa pergunta era boa, tive o maior esforço para responder o mais completo possível. E acho que já demostrei que sei o que estou falando, ainda mais em uma questão tão básica quanto isto, e o que eu ganho é um negativo. Maravilha.

Comment: Aqui não é fórum mais também não é bola de cristal. Quando algum membro qualquer citar os erros, eu naturalmente os corrigirei. Não tenho problemas com isso. O negativo (que foi meu) tem mais relação com o problema proposto, do que com a coerência do conteúdo. Não voto em um post porque acho ele bom. Voto se ele estiver correto em relação ao problema. É um critério diferente que uso, diferente de muitos membros, e isso não é um problema para mim. Você domina bem o assunto, e isso é louvável. Mas infelizmente não tem relação prática com o problema citado.

Comment: Leia minha resposta, está tudo lá o que está errado. Não corrigir é um direito seu. Justamente por não ser bola de cristal, só você poderia responder do jeito que você queria. Eu respondi o que é útil para todos. Minha resposta resolve 100% dos problemas relatados na pergunta, não resolve o que não está na pergunta.

Comment: Eu vou deixar em aberto. Porque sua postagem não ajudou muito a resolver meu problema (que já foi solucionado, com outras informações).
Aqueles que passarem pelo mesmo problema decidirão. Pelo menos a sua edição da pergunta ficou boa. A postagem ficou menos prolixa.